# JDownloader2: Formatting links for Linkgrabber

Tags: jdownloader

Is there any way of formatting a list of links in a text file, so JDownloader's Linkgrabber knows the package name I want?

For example:

- {{packagename1}}http://link-a
- {{packagename1}}http://link-b
- {{packagename2}}http://link-c
- {{packagename3}}http://link-d
- {{packagename4}}http://link-e
- {{packagename4}}http://link-f

Will put **link-a** and **link-b** in **"packagename1"**, **link-c** in **"packagename2"**, **link-d** in **"packagename3"**, and **link-e** and **link-f** in **"packagename4"**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone in Reddit pointed me to the solution.

If we look in **Settings / Packagizer**, there's a rule editor.

A custom rule can be made that takes links in the format:

> http://link-a#packagename=packagename1

Which puts the downloads found in the link in a package named "packagename1".

(Original image by the user that provided the answer, [grooters](https://www.reddit.com/user/grooters/))

[image]